# Update android application remotely

Tags: android

how to update an android third party application on mobile with user permission?
We are developing one product.client installed it from our company website.
How to update it remotely?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The means that you used to install the application in the first place generally gives you a way of notifying the user of the availability of an update, however with one exception they have to choose to install the update - you can't force it.

If the application came from the android market, that has a scheme for checking for updates which the use will have the option of installing.

If you emailed the apk to the user as an attachment, or called their attention to its availability on a website, you can do the same with the replacement.

Same story if you had them install it from their PC via the sdk or "sideload wonder machine".

(The only "mandatory" sort of upgrade I know of is for the mobile carrier to trigger an OTA update as is used to update the android system itself, and include a new apk as part (or all) of the payload.  Even this may be able to be deferred for a while)

Answer (score 0):

Now don't quote me on this but I'm pretty sure u cant because when you download the program threw a website its not registered with the market and that's where the update come from and again I'm not to sure but I'm pretty sure you''ll have to contact android market and email them and see if u can get it on the market or post the program with the update every time you want it to update the program

Answer (score -1):

I am developing several applications on android, and I need a method to remotely update the application on the beta testers' phones. I found a few services which enable the application to check a server and see if there is a new version available, in which case the user can get notified.
These are:

- [push-link](https://www.push-link.com) Free - Currently doesn't work for me, but looks promising
- [hockeykit](http://hockeykit.net/) - Free/Paid - Supports both Android and iOS
- OpenIntents - Update checker www.openintents.org/en/node/203 - Free