# How to make Pepper QiSDK robot full reboot with sensor check?

Tags: android, pepper

Greeting QiSDK Pepper robot community !

We know that there is an option to make Pepper QiSDK Android to reboot with full sensor check (long reboot), but we have forgotten how to make that happen and can't find instructions.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

The Qi SDK relies on the Android SDK, and the latter does not provide a programmatic way to reboot the device. So the short answer is that **you cannot**.

But with a bit of creativity and a bunch of know-how, who knows...
Though it is not documented, *the API for NAO 2.8 usually works for Pepper 2.9*. So you can use libqi to connect, authenticate, and call [ALSystem.reboot](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao6/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-core/alsystem/alsystem-api#ALSystemProxy::reboot). Note that you will be able to authenticate only if you know the password of the robot, i.e. if you own the robot.

I had other bad ideas to reboot the tablet, but as discussed in the comments, this is not relevant since you want to reboot the robot and have it do the full check-up. I keep them here for the record:

> 1. I found [this page about "Device Control"](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/device-management#remotely_reboot_an_android_device) that mentions rebooting a device remotely. But it comes as part of a broader framework that seems deprecated, so I doubt it works.
> 2. You could have access to the tablet via WiFi and run `adb reboot` remotely. But leaving the remote debugging enabled is not a good idea in terms of security.
> 3. You can certainly [access such system-level methods if you root the tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672821/remote-app-update-and-restart-for-unattended-field-deployed-android-phones). But this is a staggering security hazard.

Comment: That's a good answer for rebooting the device, thank you.
Though, I was asking specifically about Pepper 2.9 functionality, which was shown to us some time ago at SoftBank Robotics in Paris. Pepper was able to make reboot with sensor re-check that helped if some parts struggle to start. It was connected to somehow rebooting Pepper (maybe through chest button). But official chest button documentation doesn't state such an option.
If It was deprecated with API 7 update, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Oh, right. Then only `ALSystem.reboot` would reboot the whole robot.